# SQL query for XML data

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath

I have a SQL Server database table with a column called `XML` that contains XML data which is structured like this:

```xml
<Item xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://test/data">
  <Roots>
    <Root>
      <Name>Field Name</Name>
      <Value>Field Value</Value>
    </Root>
    <Root>
      <Name>Field Name</Name>
      <Value>Field Value</Value>
    </Root>
</Roots>
```

I want to use T-SQL to get the `Value` where `Name = Total`. I have tried the following but it isn't returning any data:

```sql
SELECT [XML]
FROM [BusinessAccount]
WHERE [XML].value('(/Root/Name)[13]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') LIKE '%Total%'
```

If anyone could tell me where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Are there multiple `<Name>` nodes? if so then post more XML.

Comment: @Salman A yes there are multiple the one i'm looking for is the 13th instance

Comment: So it is `<root><name/><value/></root> <root><name/><value/></root>` or `<root><name/><value/> <name/><value/> <name/><value/> </root>`?

Comment: Show some actual XML that is representative of your problem. Not pseudo code so we have to guess what you are trying to do

Comment: @SalmanA I have amended my post to include more

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the required `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` for your XML and the path is incorrect.

If you want to bring back rows where the 13th element consists of the text `Total` you can use the below.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://test/data') 
SELECT [XML]
FROM [BusinessAccount]
WHERE 1 = [XML].exist('(/Item/Roots/Root/Name)[13][text() = "Total"]')
```

Otherwise you can add the `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` to your original query and fix the path there too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify namespaces. You can then match `<Name>` and `<Value>` pairs and extract the contents of `<Value>` like so:

```sql
SELECT NameNode.value('declare namespace x="http://test/data"; (../x:Value)[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM [BusinessAccount]
CROSS APPLY [XML].nodes('declare namespace x="http://test/data"; //x:Root/x:Name') AS n(NameNode)
WHERE NameNode.value('.', 'varchar(100)') = 'Total'
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=08913b2d3e340d9b08f7230d39cc981f)